# comparison not possible in django 1.7 template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.7

When i tried to compare something in template am getting invalid result.
My code`

```
{% for permission in fileshare.permission.all %}



{{permission.user}}{{user.username}}



{% if permission.user == user.username %}
  Yes


{%endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

`

This is the code. the value in

permission.user and user.username result the same value. however yes is not printed. Why it is so, How can i correct it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{% ifequal permission|stringformat:"s"  user|stringformat:"s" %}

Answer (score 1):

`permission.user` is a `User`. `user.username` is a `unicode`. Try using either `permission.user.username` or `user` instead.

Comment: Verify the object types.